# save image automatically with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script that crops an image from the video stream.

```
    let ctx = image.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(results.image, croprect.x, croprect.y, croprectwidth, croprectheight, 0, 0, 300, 200);
```

In HTML

```
      <div id="image-div">
            <canvas id="image" width="300" height="200"></canvas>                
      </div>
```

Now I need to do some image processing manipulation with it. I do 'Save as' for the test but how to do it automatically?

I tried

```
    const canvas = document.getElementById('image');
    const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    console.log(dataURL);
```

In the console, it gives an URL but when I open it, it is just a blank (white) rectangle (correct size 300x200)
I want to save it to my local folder and to the backend later when the second step (image processing) of the script will work.

Comment: Where is the video (or image) coming from, relative to the page?

Comment: video from the camera - same page, same file.

Comment: You're using `https://` to serve the page? My suspicion is that the image is protected for some reason, also known as "tainted". Usually this is because of cross-domain, `file://`, or possibly `http://`. You generally can't access the content of tainted images due to security. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image).